# How is UK holiday allowance advertised?

Tags: united-kingdom, leave

[This page](https://www.gov.uk/holiday-entitlement-rights/entitlement) on the government's website says that the statutory minimum is 28 days.

I have seen job adverts that range from 22-25 days holiday allowance. It doesn't seem likely that they are advertising that they are breaking the law, so how should I interpret the total amount of holiday given?

Comment: For what it's worth, "white collar" salaried jobs in the US typically start with two weeks' (10 days) vacation plus whatever "bank holidays" and site closings and "floating holidays the company offers (which may vary a bit; for my employer that's typically about 11 days), and with sick days counted separately. Fairly senior or long-serving staff may get up to 20-25 vacation days. Occasionally companies will offer additional time or longer periods (paid sabbaticals) as rewards for long and/or significant service. So seeing a minimum of 28 days sorta boggles me a bit.

Comment: @keshlam Staring holiday at Reed Elsevier in the uk was 29 days plus bh

Answer (score 7):

This is because of how the employers decide treat bank (ie public holidays)  holidays - these examples are obviously quoting entitement excluding the public holidays.

Most workers who work a 5-day week must receive 28 days’ paid annual leave per year. An employer can include bank holidays as part of statutory annual leave.

England has 8 bank holidays the other parts of the UK have slightly different holidays.

Comment: Should I interpret 22 days as being 30 days then?

Comment: @user759 did the advert not say? but I would assume so

Comment: In the UK, you should interpret "22 days" as "22 days plus bank holidays"; mentioning 30 days anywhere will just lead to confusion. On bank holidays you just don't turn up for work unless your company asks you and pays overtime.

Comment: Agree with answer and comments, but note that the Food Service industry (cafes, sandwich shops, ?? pubs/bars ??) does NOT operate on this basis, as they DO expect to open on BHs.